# External Hive tables needing load step

Tags: c#, azure, hive, azure-hdinsight

I want to write directly to log files in blog storage from my app and then run hive queries over these log files.

Am i correct in thinking i can create external hive tables which use these files directly. Do i still need to run a load step ie

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'path to the source file' INTO TABLE database name.table     name;
```

before each hive query run in order to pick up the new data. Or will the query include new rows written to the log from web app automatically?

Also how can I write to the hive connected log file in a way that respects the multiple part files that Hive uses. So that as i write to the logs i am writing to the correct log file in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to update tables while you are reading, you should consider using Hive Streaming API. [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest) is a link to the document describing more.